# Jacoco only cover androidTest directory not test in Android Studio.What should I do?

Tags: android, junit, jacoco

I have a question that my jacoco can cover androidTest directory not test directory.How can I do make jacoco also covered test directory.

This is my gradle

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"
buildTypes {
    debug{
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}
jacoco {
toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")}
```

When I run gradlew createDebugCoverageReport. It worked. But only AndroidTest covered . Junit not. In project of Android Studio, only androidTest directory covered,test directory not covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I used [android-junit-jacoco-plugin](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin).This plugin solved my problem.But if you use this plugin,the unit test have to be all success.If not,The coverage report will not be created by jacoco.

Comment: How do you used this plugin? I have same problem after using this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my jacoco setup which covers not only androidTest directory and also able to work with different flavors.

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.7.201606060606"
}

project.afterEvaluate {
// Grab all build types and product flavors
def buildTypes = android.buildTypes.collect { type ->
    type.name
}
def productFlavors = android.productFlavors.collect { flavor ->
    flavor.name
}
// When no product flavors defined, use empty
if (!productFlavors) productFlavors.add('')
productFlavors.each { productFlavorName ->
    buildTypes.each { buildTypeName ->

        // If buildtype and flavor combo is not available, skip
        if (ignoreBuildFlavor(productFlavorName, buildTypeName)) {
            return
        }

        def sourceName, sourcePath
        if (!productFlavorName) {
            sourceName = sourcePath = "${buildTypeName}"
        } else {
            sourceName = "${productFlavorName}${buildTypeName.capitalize()}"
            sourcePath = "${productFlavorName}/${buildTypeName}"
        }
        def testTaskName = "test${sourceName.capitalize()}UnitTest"
        // Create coverage task of form 'testFlavorTypeCoverage' depending on 'testFlavorTypeUnitTest'
        task "${testTaskName}Coverage"(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "$testTaskName") {
            group = "Reporting"
            description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports on the ${sourceName.capitalize()} build."
            classDirectories = fileTree(
                    dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/${sourcePath}",
                    excludes: ['**/R.class',
                               '**/R$*.class',
                               '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                               '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
                               '**/BuildConfig.*',
                               '**/Manifest*.*',
                               '**/*$Lambda$*.*', // Jacoco can not handle several "$" in class name.
                               '**/*$inlined$*.*', // Kotlin specific, Jacoco can not handle several "$" in class name.
                               '**/*Module.*', // Modules for Dagger.
                               '**/*Dagger*.*', // Dagger auto-generated code.
                               '**/*MembersInjector*.*', // Dagger auto-generated code.
                               '**/*_Provide*Factory*.*',// Dagger auto-generated code.
                               '**/*$Icepick*.*']
            )
            def coverageSourceDirs = [
                    "src/main/java",
                    "src/$productFlavorName/java",
                    "src/$buildTypeName/java"
            ]
            additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
            sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
            executionData = files("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec")
            reports {
                xml.enabled = true
                html.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add this line to your build.gradle:

```
apply from: "jacoco.gradle"
```

Comment: Sorry,it not worked yet. It also covered AndroidTest directory(package/app/src/androidTest).When I delete the testCase in AndroidTest directory,it covered also 0%. However I had written testCase using Junit in test directory(package/app/src/test).

Comment: I have ran gradlew task . It has shown connectedAndroidTest - Installs and runs instrumentation tests for all flavors on connected devices And test - Run unit tests for all variants. I mean that I want to jacoco also cover   unit test not only instrumentation test.

Comment: So you want to calculate test coverage only according to the test folder excluding the androidTest, right?

Comment: Yes,I only want the jacoco cover test folder.But I failed.